# vue js - implementing a tree, nested component vs single

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tree, components

I'm looking at this:
https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/pnqzspoe/

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <div
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      @click="toggle"
      @dblclick="changeType">
      {{ model.name }}
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ open ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    </div>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item
        class="item"
        v-for="(model, index) in model.children"
        :key="index"
        :model="model">
      </item>
      <li class="add" @click="addChild">+</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    model: Object
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function () {
      return this.model.children &&
        this.model.children.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
        this.$emit("expand")  // doesn't work properly
      }
    },
    changeType: function () {
      if (!this.isFolder) {
        Vue.set(this.model, 'children', [])
        this.addChild()
        this.open = true
      }
    },
    addChild: function () {
      this.model.children.push({
        name: 'new stuff'
      })
    }
  }
})
```

And I want to implement some features here:
1. Node selecting functionality. So each node will have a 'selected' property whether it is selected or not.
2. An 'expand' event which will fire when a node is expanded (to load nodes via ajax).

**The problem:**
The 'expand' event is going only one level up. So it will not be work properly. I've figured two solutions: creating an event bus and passing it to each  instance. Or  creating a wrapper component and pass it to all children and use it as an event bus.
Also I would like to manage all the selected nodes in one place, so I'll have to duplicate this data on both the nodes and in another element.

Because of this I am confusing whether to nest components like that, or maybe just create a single  component, and pass it all the data. The overhead here is that I will have to iterate (recursion?) all the nodes in order to add additional attributes like 'selected', and 'open'. (and vue already iterate recursively in order to make properties reactive)

So what is the better option - nested  components, or one  component?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need nested component, it will make the logic complex.

Below is my solution for lazy load one node (expand):

1. add one prop = actions, which allow parent component/view register its event, then bind to the click event.
2. parent component/view defines its lazy load function, then bind `<item :actions="{your lazy load function}">`

You can do the similar thing for the selected.

The codes will be like below:

```js
var demoData = {
  name: 'My Tree',
  children: [
    { name: 'hello' },
    { name: 'wat' },
    {
      name: 'child folder',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'hello' },
            { name: 'wat' }
          ]
        },
        { name: 'hello' },
        { name: 'wat' },
        {
          name: 'child folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'hello' },
            { name: 'wat' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    model: Object,
    'actions': {
      type: Object,
      default: ()=>{ return {
          'loadNode': function(clickedObj){console.log('default',clickedObj)},
          'selectedChange': function(node){console.log('default',node)}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function () {
      return this.model.children &&
        this.model.children.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
        this.$emit("expand")  // doesn't work properly
      }
    },
    changeType: function () {
      if (!this.isFolder) {
        Vue.set(this.model, 'children', [])
        this.addChild()
        this.open = true
      }
    },
    addChild: function () {
      this.model.children.push({
        name: 'new stuff'
      })
    }
  }
})

app = new Vue({ //not vue, it is Vue
el: "#app",
data: {
  treeData: demoData,
  selected: {}
},
methods: {
  myLoadNode: function (parent) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if(!parent.children) {
        this.$set(parent, 'children', [])
      }
      parent.children.push(
        {
          name: 'ajax folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'ajax a1' },
            { name: 'ajax a2' }
          ]
        }
      )
    }, 500)
  },
  mySelectedChange: function (node) {
    // if each node has unique id, use 
    // this.$set(this.selected, node.id, true) will be better
    this.$set(this.selected, JSON.stringify(node), true)
  }
}
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Menlo, Consolas, monospace;
  color: #444;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: dot;
}
.load-button1{
  background-color:red
}
.load-button2{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <div
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      @click="toggle"
      @dblclick="changeType"
      >
      <a class="load-button1" @click="actions.loadNode(model)">Load</a>
      <a class="load-button2" @click="actions.selectedChange(model)">Select</a>
      {{ model.name }}
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ open ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    </div>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item
        class="item"
        v-for="(model, index) in model.children"
        :key="index"
        :model="model"
        :actions="{'loadNode':actions.loadNode, 'selectedChange':actions.selectedChange}"
        >
      </item>
      <li class="add" @click="addChild">+</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>
<div id="app">
  <item
    class="item"
    :model="treeData"
    :actions="{'loadNode':myLoadNode, 'selectedChange': mySelectedChange}">
  </item>
  <p>{{selected}}
</div>
```